# Best Clustering Algorithm for High Dimensional Vectors

Tags: python, machine-learning, cluster-analysis

I am attempting to use some sort of clustering method on a set of datapoint vectors which have 45 dimensions. I'm fairly new to clustering data points and was wondering if anyone could point out appropriate methods to utilize? I was attempted using K-Means Clustering but was wondering if the dimensionality of my data might be too large for this?

Comment: it is not too large, not at all.

Answer (score 1):

45 dimensions is not particularly high. It's at best "medium" dimensionality, so most algorithms *could* work.

Usually it's not so much a matter of the number of dimensions, but rather how well they are preprocessed. With bad preprocessing, 2 dimensions can be a problem if the signal in one attribute is drowned by the noise in the other.

There is no automatic way to get this right, otherwise it would be in all the libraries. Scaling can help, but can also harm. It's up to the user to prepare the data and choose parameters (such as distance functions and algorithms) to achieve the desired effect, because there is no computable equation fot "desirable".

Answer (score 0):

[Complexity of K-means clustering is O(qknp)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5148156/), where q is the number of iterations, k is the number of clusters, n is the sample size, and p is the dimensionality.

You probably don't want to change k.

Most of the time q is determined during the execution of the K-Means algorithm, It stops when cluster-means stop changing.

Most of the time you want to use all of your data, but you may reduce your sample size, this will decrease accuracy of your results.

You may reduce dimensions of your data by using principal component analysis. This results in some(little in most cases) information loss. which effects your results.